# Django region data MultiPolygonField

Tags: python, django, geolocation, geodjango

Forgive me ignorance on this. I'm using Geo Django's built in `MultiPolygonField` to store region data. The data stored in the DB for that field looks like this...

```
0106000020E6100000010000000103000000010000000700000000000000003C1EC023000000E690504000000000000D414023000000E63353400000000000344740460000004CD34C400000000080314240460000004C60474000000000003A21408D00000098EE3E400000000000BE34C08D00000098483F4000000000003C1EC023000000E6905040
```

I would like to use the region data here: [http://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html#)# but saves the data as a `.poly` file that describes the extent of this region.

My question is, how do I convert the `.poly` data [here](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe.poly) to match how MultiPolygonField describes it in the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value from the DB that you show is the Well Known Binary (WKB) format of a geometry. If you are using PostGIS, you can look at the same geometry in the Well Known Text (WKT) format, which is more human readable. Here is a query to show the WKB geometry you posted as WKT:

```
SELECT ST_AsEWKT('0106000020E6100000010000000103000000010000000700000000000000003C1EC023000000E690504000000000000D414023000000E63353400000000000344740460000004CD34C400000000080314240460000004C60474000000000003A21408D00000098EE3E400000000000BE34C08D00000098483F4000000000003C1EC023000000E6905040'::geometry)
```

To store a geometry in GeoDjango, you need to use one of the input formats that it acccepts see the Django documentation for [GEOSGeometry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#geosgeometry) and [OGRGeometry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/gdal/#ogrgeometry).

So you need to write a parser to convert the coordinates you have in the .poly file to a format known to Django (such as WKT or geojson).

Here is an example on how to construct a multi polygon with the first few coordinates of the .poly data you linked. Notice that the last coordinate needs to be the same as the first to close the polygon.

```
poly = GEOSGeometry('MULTIPOLYGON(((-5.86333200   8.14347501,   -6.70445600   7.47862301,   -3.44929601   6.28074401,   -3.08375301   3.08165901,   -1.71378401   3.10939901,   -5.86333200   8.14347501)))')
```

To store the geometry, you can pass the WKT data directly as input to your MultiPolygonField, or you can construct the `poly` geometry object as in the example, and pass that to your field.